# $S_4$ is a subgroup of $PSL(2,7)$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Why is $S_4$ subgroup of PSL(2,7)? 
I found that symmetric group $S_4$ is subgroup of PSL(2,7), but cannot find any relation between these two groups.

Comment: What you are asking is not clear. You know that $S_4$ is a subgroup of $PSL(2,7)$, so what are you really  asking ? A geometric reason ?  What do you mean by "relation" between these groups ?

Comment: Take a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PSL(2,7)

Comment: Answer: because $7\equiv -1 \bmod 8$.

Answer (score 0):

The subgroups of $PSL(2,q)$ are known by a theorem of Dickson. In particular,
the symmetric group $S_4$ is a subgroup in  $PSL(2,q)$ if $q^2\equiv 1\bmod 16$.

Reference: B. Huppert, Endliche Gruppen I, Springer, Berlin, 1967.